# How & works in 7 & 1 in php

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Can anybody help me to understand, how the following code works ? I know it will return 1 if for odd number and 0 for even number.

```
echo (7 & 1);  // result 1
echo (6 & 1);  // result 0
```

I think the numbers are converted to its binary. Please correct if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Because odd numbers have their LSB set to 1, & is a bitwise and operator.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 5):

```
7 = 0000111b
1 = 0000001b
------------
& = 0000001b = 1
```

And for 6:

```
6 = 0000110b
1 = 0000001b
------------
& = 0000000b = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are performing a AND operation on the numbers, so

```
Dec     BINARY   Output
7  ===  0111
1  ===  0001
------------------------
AND  op 0001     1


Dec     BINARY
6  ===  0110
1  ===  0001
------------------------
AND  op 0000     0
```

**Like Wise,**

```
Dec     BINARY
7  ===  0111
6  ===  0110
------------------------
AND  op 0110         6
```

Comment: `1  ===  0001`, not `0000`